# how do I connect to a windows mysql server for XtraBackup

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, cross-platform, percona

I have a mysql server running on windows.

I'd like to use XtraBackup to back it up, but I understand that only runs on Linux.

I have XtraBackup installed on a Linux machine on the same network.
From this Linux machine I can query the mysql database using a connection string that contains:

```
Data Source=192.168.1.60;port=3306;
```

However when I try to run xtraBackup it doesn't seem to allow you to specify the IP address, however you can specify a .sock file (using the   ***--socket=*** option).

I have local access to the mysql files (on the windows server), which I specify by passing this argument to XtraBackup:

```
--datedir="/media/powerhouse_G/Data Files/mySQL"
```

How do I fix this, either by supplying the IP address, or creating a .sock file?

Answer (score 0):

XtraBackup needs local access to the MySQL datadir. It can't do its job with only remote MySQL protocol access.

The only solution for using XtraBackup on Windows that I've read is to use Docker to run XtraBackup within a container, which has access to your datadir.

Details are here:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/03/20/running-percona-xtrabackup-windows-docker/

It might work also running xtrabackup on a Linux host that has access to map the Windows drive.

But regardless, you're in uncharted territory. I don't know anyone who is doing what you're doing. Virtually everyone in the open-source community uses Linux for their MySQL Server.

You could also try paying for a MySQL Enterprise license. That gives you access to [MySQL Enterprise Backup](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/backup.html), which runs on Windows. MEB works similarly to Percona XtraBackup, but PXB has more features (and PXB is free, whereas MEB is only for paying enterprise customers).

Comment: sorry, I should have said that I do have local access to the datadir, I'll add it to my question.

Comment: yes I did, thanks very much, I will give that a go.
Obviously it would be better if the server was on Linux to start with.

Comment: no idea how to create a .sock file that would point to the IP address though?